# Error occurred while downloading files from Administration Server for deployment request .Underlying error is: "null"

Tags: web, java-7, weblogic12c

I am not able to update the web application on managed weblogic server(However I am successfully deployed that same app on admin server), Every time I tried to deploy it on managed server, I am getting

```
 [DeploymentService:290066]Error occurred while downloading files from Administration Server for
 deployment request "62,790,652,848,356". Underlying error is: "null"
```

I have taken the following action to solve this problem.

**1) stoped both admin and managed server and start those.(The admin server is sucessfully started but the Managed server is generating the above error and started in admin mode.**

**2) took backup of tmp folder and deleted old tmp folder and restarted both admin and managed server , then also I am getting the same error.**

I need your support to resolve this problem as I am able to access the site , which is on production.

The same sever was working before but today when I tried to deployed the web app changes which was a small change(Included a coulmn in my jsp file) .The managed server is started generating this error. Now even if I rollback the changes and try to deploy this , it is still generating the same error[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Managed server is at different host and Admin server running at different machine.

Go to AdminServer logs and review the AdminServer.log and check in case any  errors  related to something like unable to check config.xml.orgfile because file  have root permissions(it happened when someone started Admin server by root). check all the files at Admin Server under /config and see if any file have different permission. Change the  permission  on this file and restart the  server and it may works. it might have happened because Admin Server was started by root( mistake) instead of oracle that own the domain.

Comment: This also happened when the target was named incorrectly. I re-installed the managed app with the correct target name in a WLST command, deploy. Then the application started correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your target name is correct in your WLST `deploy` command.

Answer (score 0):

start managed server using the command

nohup ./startManagedWeblogic.sh 'instance_name' http://adminserverurl:port &

It should work perfectly